# If statement is working, but return inside of if statement is not. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm working on HackerRank's problem "Comparing Two Linked Lists". My function that compares the two Linked Lists is below:

```
bool compare_lists(SinglyLinkedListNode* head1, SinglyLinkedListNode* head2) {
    if(head1 != nullptr && head2 != nullptr){
        if(head1->data != head2->data){
            return 0;
        }
        compare_lists(head1->next, head2->next);
    }
    else if(head1 != head2){
        cout << head1 << endl << head2 << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

The function works to first check whether corresponding values are different between the two lists. If values are different, the first nested if statement is tripped and the functions returns 0. The else if statement works to check whether the lists are different lengths. If one or both of the heads are the nullptr and the two heads are not equal in value (because one is the nullptr and one has a real address) then the two lists have different lengths. The else if statement is tripped in the code (I know because the cout statement in the else if statement prints to the console), but the function won't return. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You make a recursive call to `compare_lists`, but then ignore its return value and `return 1` unconditionally. The recursive call has no effect.

Comment: It should only get to return 1 if it gets to that point in the code, i.e. if it is the same length and has the same values in all spots. I might be wrong about this, but then why does it successfully return 0 when corresponding values are different? @IgorTandetnik

Comment: Think about what the very first, top-level `compare_lists` call is doing. Say both nodes are not null, and have the same data. Then it calls `compare_lists` recursively - but there is no `return` statement there, so the execution proceeds to the very last `return 1` statement.

Comment: Ah, so I thought that a return 0 would break the recursion and return a 0 back to main. Is this not true? Because if neither node is the nullptr and they don't have the same value, then we'd get to the last node where either one is the nullptr and the other is not, which should return 0, or where the value is not the same, which would return 0, or it will make its way all the way to return 1 which means that the lists are the same. This was how I thought it would work @IgorTandetnik

Comment: When `main` calls some function, you don't expect `return` within that function to also return from `main` and terminate your program, do you? Similarly, when `compare_lists` calls `compare_lists` recursively, a `return` within this second call doesn't magically terminate the first call - it merely returns a value, which that first call could then use in some way (e.g. by in turn returning that value to its caller). But you don't in fact use that return value in any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to answer this question: What does the method return when `head1 == head2` (1) and `head1->data == head2->data` (2) and neither of them is `nullptr` (3) ?

```
bool compare_lists(SinglyLinkedListNode* head1, SinglyLinkedListNode* head2) {
    //if(head1 != nullptr && head2 != nullptr){
    if (true) {  // neither of them is nullptr (3)
        //if(head1->data != head2->data){
        if (false) { // (2)
            return 0;
        }
        compare_lists(head1->next, head2->next);
    }
    //else if(head1 != head2){
    else if (false) { // (1)
        cout << head1 << endl << head2 << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

After removing dead branches we are left with:

```
bool compare_lists(SinglyLinkedListNode* head1, SinglyLinkedListNode* head2) {
    compare_lists(head1->next, head2->next);
    return 1;
}
```

What does this method return?

> `1`. Always! (given (1),(2) and (3) are all `true`)

How to fix it?

> You are ignoring the return value of the recursive call. Don't do that.

*PS* Maybe it helps to consider what happens in a modified version (only the reduced example, but you can apply the same modification in your actual code):

```
bool some_other_function(SinglyLinkedListNode* head1, SinglyLinkedListNode* head2);

bool compare_lists(SinglyLinkedListNode* head1, SinglyLinkedListNode* head2) {
    some_other_function(head1->next, head2->next);
    return 1;
}
```

Once you understood that you can add a definition for that other function:

```
bool some_other_function(SinglyLinkedListNode* head1, SinglyLinkedListNode* head2) {
    return compare_lists(head1,head2);
}
```

Comment: Okay, I think I was missing something very basic about the way that return works in C++.  I believe I understand this now, but I'll need to think more about it. Thank you very much!

Comment: @AndrewLubrino this is a extremely common mistake with recursion. I'd be really curious to understand what misunderstanding causes it, but I am afraid it would take a longer discussion to find that out. Don't worry and better do the opposite of "I'll try this and think about it later.". Make sure to understand it now ;)

Comment: Okay! I'm looking at other Stack Overflow posts about this issue now to try to understand exactly why this function would need to return the recursive call for it to work. But at least I know what I'm looking for. Thanks again! @idclev 463035818

Comment: @AndrewLubrino I added a PS. The thing is that the mistake has actually not much to do with recursion itself (but for some reason it appears often with recursion)

Comment: so my initial understanding was that when a return was called, it would immediately exit the function and return the value back to main. If that was true, the original code I had might work right? Since it would never get to return 1 if the function returns 0 at an earlier point in the code when one of the if statements that checks for similarity is tripped. But I'm guessing now that return only returns to the "previous" function in the recursion. Still I'm confused because the function did work in 5 out of 7 test cases and successfully returned 0 in some cases. @idclev 463035818

Comment: @AndrewLubrino sorry if I invited a misunderstanding. Comments are not for extended discussion. Unfortunately they are the wrong medium for this. As much as I'd like to help you further, I rather suggest you to discuss this with some fellow face to face, this will help you much more

Comment: @AndrewLubrino though, yes, `return` only returns to the caller, not to the top of the call stack, otherwise you would always return to `main`

Comment: okay. I completely understand this now. The function could still return 0 if the difference is in the very first node, but will otherwise always return 1. Thanks so much! @idclev 463035818

Answer (score 0):

You aren't returning the recursive call to `compare_lists`:

```
bool compare_lists(SinglyLinkedListNode* head1, SinglyLinkedListNode* head2) {
    if(head1 != nullptr && head2 != nullptr){
        if(head1->data != head2->data){
            return 0;
        }
        return compare_lists(head1->next, head2->next); // return was missing here
    }
    else if(head1 != head2){
        cout << head1 << endl << head2 << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: I'm honestly not sure what this means. How can one return a function? The function returns bool values.

Comment: This doesn't return a function - it calls the function and returns the result of that function call.

Comment: Okay, I'll try this and think about it later. Thank you!